# Only one command executed in expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to telnet into a system and execute a number of commands on that system. So I was trying this expect script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect                                                               

spawn telnet localhost 42000                                                    
expect "login:"                                                                 
send "root\r"                                                                   
expect  -re "-sh-4.1#"                                                          
send "echo HELLO\r"                                                             
expect  -re "-sh-4.1#"                                                          
send "echo WORLD\r"
```

As it turns out, only the first echo command is being executed and then the telnet session terminates. I have seen some examples of expect where multiple commands can be executed after logging into a telnet or ssh session.

So what is wrong in this script that I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the next `expect` statement, then only `expect` will wait for it.

You just have to add one more line as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect                                                               

spawn telnet localhost 42000                                                    
expect "login:"                                                                 
send "root\r"                                                                   
expect  -re "-sh-4.1#"                                                          
send "echo HELLO\r"                                                             
expect  -re "-sh-4.1#"                                                          
send "echo WORLD\r"   
expect  -re "-sh-4.1#"
```

This is because without that We will be missing out what is happening the spawned telnet session as `expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session and there is no more code which is why your script got terminated, thereby terminating your telnet session.